# Event Handling During Countdown Timer with UIProgressView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I hope this is not a dumb question, since I've already googled and read a lot of other similar questions, but I have been messing around with this issue for days.

I have implemented a countdown timer using NSTimer and UIProgressView, but I want to do more with this time, i.e. play an alert sound when the timer reaches the last 10 seconds.

Here's what I've done:

```
-(void) updateTimer
{
    if (time <= 0.0f)
    {

     //Invalidate timer when time reaches 0
         [timer invalidate];
         [[AudioManager sharedManager] muteGameClock1Sound];    
         [self showGameOverViewController];
     }
     else
     {
         time -= 0.1;
         [timeProgressView setProgress:time/totalTime animated:YES];

         if (time < 10 && pauseView)
         {
            [[AudioManager sharedManager] playGameClock1Sound];
         }
     }

}
```

and in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
timeProgressView.progress = 1;
time = [ConfigFileManager sharedManager].timePerQuestion.intValue * [DatabaseManager sharedManager].numberOfQuestions;
totalTime = [ConfigFileManager sharedManager].timePerQuestion.intValue * [DatabaseManager sharedManager].numberOfQuestions;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1f target: self             selector: @selector(updateTimer) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

and the `pauseGame` method:

```
-(IBAction)pauseGame:(id)sender
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.0 alpha: 0.4];   
    pauseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 150)];
    pauseView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.0 alpha: 0.4];
    pauseView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);
    pauseView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    if ([pauseView.layer respondsToSelector: @selector(setCornerRadius:)])
        [(id) pauseView.layer setCornerRadius: 10];

    resumeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    resumeButton.center = CGPointMake(pauseView.bounds.size.width/4, pauseView.bounds.size.height/2);
    [resumeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].buttonBackground] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [resumeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].buttonBackgroundSelected] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [resumeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].messageResumeButton] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [resumeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(resumeTheGame) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    restartButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    restartButton.center = CGPointMake(pauseView.bounds.size.width/2, pauseView.bounds.size.height/2);
    [restartButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].buttonBackground] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [restartButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].buttonBackgroundSelected] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [restartButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].messageReplayButton] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [restartButton addTarget:self action:@selector(restartTheGame) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    quitButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    quitButton.center = CGPointMake(pauseView.bounds.size.width*3/4, pauseView.bounds.size.height/2);
    [quitButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].buttonBackground] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [quitButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].buttonBackgroundSelected] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [quitButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[ConfigFileManager sharedManager].messageQuitButton] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [quitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showGameOverViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [pauseView addSubview:resumeButton];
    [pauseView addSubview:restartButton];
    [pauseView addSubview:quitButton];
    [self.view addSubview: pauseView];
    choice1Button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    choice2Button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    choice3Button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    choice4Button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    choice5Button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    pauseButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}
```

The problem is that the `playGameClock1Sound` method is not being called in this way, but it is, when I say: `if (!pauseView && time > 10)` which is not rational, and then in this case, when the pauseButton is pressed and therefore the `pauseView` is `TRUE`, the `playGameClock1Sound` method is being called again.

I'd be really grateful if someone helps me with this stupid issue, and even more grateful if you tell me how to handle pause/resume, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show how pauseView is set? If you try something like this it may be simpler...

Everything you are doing seems fine so i think the issue is with how you are setting the pauseView bool.

Also, is the audio file you are playing shorter then or equal to the timers delay time? If it is not it will be played again before it is finished.

```
-(void) updateTimer
{
    //stop counting if the view is paused
    if(pauseView)
    {
        return;
    }

    //done
    if (time <= 0.0f)
    {
        //Invalidate timer when time reaches 0
        [timer invalidate];
        [[AudioManager sharedManager] muteGameClock1Sound]; 
        [self showGameOverViewController];
    }
    else
    {
        time -= 0.1;
        [timeProgressView setProgress:time/totalTime animated:YES]; 
        if (time < 10)
        {
            NSLog("Play some audio");
            [[AudioManager sharedManager] playGameClock1Sound];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you verrrry much miex. I added the pauseView code, and the `if (pauseView)` part is working perfect, but the sound is not still being played, although setting a breakpoint, the method seems to be called (so many times, as the time reaches 10 and counts down). Any idea?

Comment: Also I need to resume the time after the pauseView is dismissed (resumeTheGame method is called).

Comment: To resume the timer all you have to do is set pauseView to NO when it is dismissed. You have to add logic to do that. As for the audio, it looks like the comment is being posted to the console and it is going into the code block as expected, right? It seems that the only issue remaining is that playGameClock1Sound does not work. What audio manager is this that you are using? Is the audio file referenced in the project? If so, you can just use the standard ios method to play the file. http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

Comment: FYI All of the stuff you are allocating and initializing in the pauseGame function should be done once on viewDidLoad. Once everything is allocated/initialized you can just show/hide stuff and not have to recreate it all.

Comment: OK... I fixed audio play issue, but I'm unable to restart/resume the UIProgressView after restarting the game:
`-(void) restartTheGame
{
 
 [self viewDidLoad];
 [pauseView removeFromSuperview];
 choice1Button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 choice2Button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 choice3Button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 choice4Button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 choice5Button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 pauseButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [self startCountdown];
}`

Comment: `startCountdown` already exists in the viewDidLoad, but calling neither of them restarts the timer. No idea on how to resume it.

Comment: The NSTimer never actually stops. You should have a local BOOL for isPaused and set it to YES or NO when appropriate. updateTimer would then change its first line to if(isPaused == YES)... OR if you want you can continue to reference the pauseView and it will work this way... if you make restartTheGame set pauseView = nil;

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Actually this was what I was missing in order to get the timer resume when pressing the resume button:

```
pauseView = nil;
```

Added it to the `resumeTheGame` method, and the problem was solved.